# How to get today date via bootstrap datepicker after page load?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I use this code for run date picker on the textbox.Now When I click on the this input datepicker run currently .I want when page loaded get today date and put into value of this input.How to fix this?

```
  $("#ReturnDateSH_flight").datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    isRTL: true,
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
});
```

Comment: If it's an input field, try putting todays date in the `value` attribute. Or have you tried to call the `setDate` function? `$("#ReturnDateSH_flight").datepicker("setDate", new Date());`

Comment: OK.This is right .Please add answer to accept you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an input field, try putting todays date in the value attribute.

Or your could call the `setDate` function:

```
$("#ReturnDateSH_flight").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```